# Order of $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z})/\langle (4,2)\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is what I did:
any element is of the form $(a+4\mathbb{Z},b+2\mathbb{Z})$, where $a=0,1,2,3$ and $b=0,1$. So it the order should be $8$. But the answer is given to be $\infty$. 
What is the wrong in the way i did?

Comment: Can you name all elements of the group $\langle(2,2)\rangle$?

Comment: It is easy to think that you can mod out one component and then mod the other out but this isn't true, you are modding out both components simultaneously.

Comment: Some inequivalent objects: $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(0,2)$, $(0,3)$, $\dots$, $(0,17)$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Sorry, typing mistake in the question

Comment: Let's look at an example. Do you believe $(4,4)\in\langle (4,2)\rangle$?

Comment: As others have pointed out, you are assuming that $\langle(4,2)\rangle$ consists of all elements of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ of the form $(4a,2b)$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. In fact it consists of all elements of the form $(4a,2a)$ where $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hopefully, the answer should then be deducible from this.

Comment: Your mistake in yet another words: You have calculated with the group $$(\Bbb{Z}\oplus\Bbb{Z})/\langle (4,0),(0,2)\rangle.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possibly that you just misread the question, and thought it was about $\def\Z{\Bbb Z}(\Z\oplus\Z)/\langle(4,0),(0,2)\rangle$, where you are modding out be the lattice spanned by those two group elements; for that question the resulting group is indeed isomorphic to $(\Z/4\Z)\oplus(\Z/2\Z)$ and has order $8$. However in the question one is modding out only by the multiples of a single element $(4,2)$ which all lie on a single line. As a consequence, for two elements of $\Z\oplus\Z$ to become equivalent it is necessary that their difference $(a,b)$ satisfies $a-2b=0$ (and even this is not a sufficient condition). In particular any collection of points $(x,y)$ for which the expression $2x-y$ takes different values for all of them are mutually inequivalent. Then the quotient group is certainly infinite, as $2x-y$ can take infinitely many distinct values (even when taking only points with $x=0$).